# DI - Assembly wide install based on generic interface does not register its implementations

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am trying to register Interfaces and their implementations using Castle Windsor.

I have a Class called `ProductRiskStatusChecks` which implements `IChecks<IProductRisk>` where `IProductRisk` implements `IValidateDomainObject`

I tried to install these as below -

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("OpenBoxExtraBusinessLogic")
                    .BasedOn<IChecks<IValidateDomainObject>>()
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestyleSingleton());
        }
```

but it doesn't install `ProductRiskChecks` against `IChecks<IProductRisk>`
but if I do a explicit register as below it works fine

```
container.Register(Component.For<IChecks<IProductRisk>>().ImplementedBy<ProductRiskChecks>());
```

Can I here know why isn't first case registering my Checks class ?

Thanks

Comment: `IChecks<IValidateDomainObject>` and `IChecks<IProductRisk>` are different interfaces (irrespective of relationship between `IValidateDomainObject` and `IProductRisk`) so behavior looks reasonable to me (not really familiar with Castle Windsor, so just commenting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your registration does not work because of type mismatch (exactly as Alexei mentioned).

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve here but if you have multiple implementations of `IChecks<>` each with different generic parameter and you want to register them all you can go with registration using *open generics*:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("OpenBoxExtraBusinessLogic")
                      .BasedOn(typeof(ICheck<>))
                      .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                      .LifestyleSingleton())
```

Comment: thanks man this works, I tried this a few times, but didn't click to use `typeof` it works.. thanks!